# How to strip links with html contents to plain text in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, hyperlink

Requirement is:

```
"link: <http://www.google.com|www.google.com> link1: <http://www.jira.com|www.jira.com>\n\n\n"
```

Need to display it as:

```
"link: www.google.com link1: www.jira.com"
```

Any solution for this.

Comment: https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Is your input text format always the same?

Comment: Step 1) Replace all < and > with "";  Step 2) Split strings on |  The result will give you and new item in the array on every |  Step 3) Rejoin every odd item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a Regex:

```cs
Regex.Replace(
    input: "link: <http://www.google.com|www.google.com> link1: <http://www.jira.com|www.jira.com>\n\n\n",
    pattern: @"<[^|]*\|([^>]*)>",
    replacement: "$1")
```

Output:

```
link: www.google.com link1: www.jira.com
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fn99jz

Regex breakdown:

```
<       // Match literal '<'.
[^|]*   // Match all chars until reaching '|'.
\|      // Match literal '|' (needs escaping).
(       // Start capturing all chars matching the following expr.
  [^>]* // Match all chars until reaching '>'. 
)       // Stop capturing & store previous match in reference '$1'.
>       // Match literal '>'.
```

Comment: which working perfectly on the example i provided, but if there is no '|' literal present it fails to replace. for eg:- "text":"this is a link <http://www.jira.com>\u00A0\n\n\n" how we can modify the reg exp. to match these cases also.

Comment: @Geeker please update the question to specify what the desired output is in this case.